# How to correct my polynomial GCD to have the right answer between two high-order polynomial ?(in C or C++)

Tags: c++, c

I have this homework to design a polynomial GCD in C, and the program down below is my work, and it work very effective and 100% correct between low-order polynomial, such as `3x^3-3` & `2x^2-4x+2`

But when I test the high-order polynomial, the answers are always wrong, that I'm not really sure that whether my  method is only applicable for low-order polynomial or small-size calculation.

Example:

```
-6x^55+3x^54+3x^51+6x^50-6x^48+3x^47+6x^45-4x^36+2x^35+4x^33+4x^31-6x^29-2x^28+6x^26-x^25-4x^23+x^22+2x^21-2x^19+x^18+2x^16-4x^15+2x^14+2x^11+4x^10-4x^8+2x^7+4x^5
    &
-10x^31+5x^30+5x^27+10x^26-10x^24+5x^23+10x^21-10x^19+5x^18+5x^15+10x^14-10x^12+5x^11+10x^9
```

and the answer GCD should be: `2x^15-x^14-x^11-2x^10+2x^8-x^7-2x^5`

I present my code below. Please help me find where it is wrong or how can I improve the program. (And sorry I have both C and C++ in my program syntax, cause my class teacher teach both method's basic at the same time .)(For the steps that simplify coefficients in polynomial by divided GCD, it's actually because my homework demands the results to be polynomial function with irreducible integral coefficients. )

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int deg1=55, deg2=31, i, j, dr;
    long m1, n1, R1, m2, n2, R2, m3, n3, R3, m4, n4, R4, gcd1, gcd2; //m , n, R are variables to calculate GCD between integers

    int ARRAY_MAX=1000;
    printf("start\n");
    scanf("%d", &j); //just input a random number to start the calculation

    long in1[56]={0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, -4, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 2, -4, 2, 0, 1, -2, 0, 2, 1, -4, 0, -1, 6, 0, -2, -6, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 2, -4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, -6, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0, 3, -6}; 
    long in2[32]={0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, -10, 0, 10, 5, 0, 0, 5, -10, 0, 10, 0, 5, -10, 0, 10, 5, 0, 0, 5, -10};

    long long r[ARRAY_MAX];
    long long Copy1[ARRAY_MAX];
    long long Copy2[ARRAY_MAX];
    
    long long Op1[ARRAY_MAX];
    for ( i=0 ; i<=deg1 ; i++){ 
                Op1[i] =in1[i];
    }
    long long Op2[ARRAY_MAX];
    for ( i=0 ; i<=deg2 ; i++){ 
                Op2[i] =in2[i];
    }
    long long Op3[ARRAY_MAX];
    long long *Result = new long long[ARRAY_MAX];
        
    if(deg1==0||deg2==0){
         for ( i=0 ; i<=ARRAY_MAX ; i++){
            Result[i]=0;
            Result[0]=1;
        }
    }
    else{
        for (i=0 ; i<=deg1 ; i++){ //find the GCD between polynomial 1's coefficients, then divide it to all coefficient 
            Copy1[i]= Op1[i];
            if(Copy1[i]<0){
                Copy1[i]= -Copy1[i];
            }   
        } 
            if (deg1>=1) {
                m1 = Copy1[0];
                n1 = Copy1[1];     
                while(n1 != 0) { 
                    R1 = m1 % n1; 
                    m1 = n1; 
                    n1 = R1; 
                }
            }
            if (deg1>=2){
                for (i=2 ; i<=deg1 ; i++){
                    n1 = Copy1[i];
                    while(n1 != 0) { 
                        R1 = m1 % n1; 
                        m1 = n1; 
                        n1 = R1;
                    }
                    if (m1==1){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
                for ( i=0 ; i<=deg1 ; i++){
                    Op1[i] = Op1[i]/m1;
                }
    
    for (i=0 ; i<=deg2 ; i++){//find the GCD between polynomial 2's coefficients, then divide it to all coefficient 
            Copy2[i]= Op2[i];
            if(Copy2[i]<0){
                Copy2[i]= -Copy2[i];
            }   
        } 
            if (deg2>=1) {
                m2 = Copy2[0];
                n2 = Copy2[1];     
                while(n2!= 0) { 
                    R2 = m2 % n2; 
                    m2 = n2; 
                    n2 = R2; 
                }
            }
            if (deg2>=2){
                for (i=2 ; i<=deg2 ; i++){
                    n2 = Copy2[i];
                    while(n2 != 0) { 
                        R2 = m2 % n2; 
                        m2= n2; 
                        n2 = R2;
                    }
                    if (m2==1){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
                for ( i=0 ; i<=deg2 ; i++){
                    Op2[i] = Op2[i]/m2;
                }
                for(i=0 ; i<=deg1 ; i++){
                        printf("%lld, ",Op1[i]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                for(i=0 ; i<=deg2 ; i++){
                        printf("%lld, ",Op2[i]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");   

    while (deg2 != 0) { //if deg2=0 the process of finding GCD is over
        if (deg1>=deg2){
            while (deg1>=deg2){
                m3= Op1[deg1];
                n3= Op2[deg2];
                    while(n3!=0){ //find the ICM between the highest order's coefficient of both polynomial, then find the number(gcd2, gcd1) to let the highest order's coefficient of both polynomial equals to ICM, finally multiply to polynomials 
                        R3=m3%n3;
                        m3=n3;
                        n3=R3;
                    }
                    gcd1=Op1[deg1]/m3;
                    gcd2=Op2[deg2]/m3;
                    if(((Op1[deg1]>0&&Op2[deg2]<0&&Op1[deg1]<-Op2[deg2])||(Op1[deg1]<0&&Op2[deg2]>0&&Op2[deg2]>-Op1[deg1]))){
                        gcd1=-gcd1;
                        gcd2=-gcd2;
                    }
                    for(i=0 ; i<=deg1 ; i++){
                        Op1[i]=Op1[i]*gcd2; 
                    }
                    for(i=0 ; i<=deg2 ; i++){
                        Op3[i]=Op2[i]*gcd1; 
                        Op1[i+deg1-deg2]=Op1[i+deg1-deg2]-Op3[i]; //the polynomial long divisor method
                    }
                    dr=deg1;
                    for(i=deg1 ; i>=1 ; i--){ //to let order of polynomial 1 update to the remainder's order
                        if(Op1[i]==0){
                            dr--;       
                        }
                        else if(Op1[i]!=0){
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    deg1=dr;
            }
        }
        for ( i=0 ; i<=deg1 ; i++){ //the GCD method
            r[i]=Op1[i];
            } 
        dr = deg1;
        for ( i=0 ; i<=deg2 ; i++){
            Op1[i]=0;
            Op1[i]=Op2[i];
            }   
        for ( i=0 ; i<=deg2; i++){
            Op2[i]=0;
            Op2[i]=r[i];
            } 
        for ( i=0 ; i<=deg2 ; i++){
            Op3[i]=0;
            }
        deg1 = deg2;
        deg2 = dr;
        for ( i=0 ; i<=dr ; i++){
            r[i]=0; 
        }
    }
    //find the GCD between result's coefficients, then divide it to all coefficient 
    
    long st[deg1+1];
    if (Op2[0] != 0)    {
        for ( i=0 ; i<=deg1 ; i++){
            Op1[i] = 0;
          }
        Op1[0] = 1;
    } 
    else {
    
        for (i=0 ; i<=deg1 ; i++){
            st[i]= Op1[i];
            if(st[i]<0){
                st[i]= -st[i];
            }   
        } 
            if (deg1>=1) {
                m4 = st[0];
                n4 = st[1];    
                while(n4 != 0) { 
                    R4 = m4 % n4; 
                    m4 = n4; 
                    n4 = R4; 
                }
            }
            if (deg1>=2){
                for (i=2 ; i<=deg1 ; i++){
                    n4 = st[i];
                    while(n4 != 0) { 
                        R4= m4 % n4; 
                        m4 = n4; 
                        n4 = R4;
                    }
                    if (m4==1){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
                for ( i=0 ; i<=deg1 ; i++){
                    Op1[i] = Op1[i]/m4;
                }
            if (Op1[deg1]<0){
                for ( i=0 ; i<=deg1 ; i++)
                    Op1[i] = -Op1[i];
                }
    }
    for(i=deg1+1;i<=ARRAY_MAX;i++){
        Op1[i]=0;
     }
     for ( i=0 ; i<=ARRAY_MAX ; i++){
            Result[i]=0;
            Result[i]=Op1[i];
    }
    }
    for(i=0 ; i<=deg1 ; i++){
                        printf("%lld, ",Result[i]);
                    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This code is neither strictly conforming C code (because it uses the C++ `new` operator) nor C++ code (because it uses variable length arrays).

Comment: The code in lines 39 to 41, which sets each coefficient to its absolute value, cannot be correct, as this perverts polynomials with coefficients of mixed signs. It might make sense to negate the whole polynomial if you want a particular coefficient, such as the highest, to be non-negative, but individually negating some of the coefficients is not correct.

Comment: Lines 43 to 67 apparently divide `OP1` by the GCD of its coefficients. This is not a correct step in computing the GCD of two polynomials.

Comment: The code continues with similar misconceptions. I recommend discarding it and starting over. To find greatest common divisor of two polynomials, use the [Euclidean algorithm for polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor). To perform the division required by this algorithm, see the article on [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).

Comment: I think  Lines 43 to 67 just the way to simplify the polynomial first, like to convert 3x^3+3 to x^3+1 ,is it wrong that affects the result?

Comment: And I've read those method, that I prevent divided the highest order coefficient directly which might cause mistake , like 1/3=1.3333 is the quotient, and I'll have to multiply it back to polynomial 1 which cause a big mistake, so I find a method to just multiply both highest order coefficient to their ICM and  substract them directly, this method's step is same as divide, but it will make other coefficient much bigger.

Comment: You can manipulate the polynomials to avoid fractions. If a(x) is being divided by b(x) and their leading coefficients are p and q, you could multiply a(x) by q/GCD(p, q), so that q will evenly divide the new leading coefficient of a(x). And then you need to remember the polynomial has been scaled by q/GCD(p, q). But this manipulation must be done correctly. Simply dividing a polynomial by the GCD of all of its coefficients is not correct.

Comment: Consider the two polynomials 3x^3+3 and 3x^3+3. They are identical, so their GCD is 3x^3+3. If you reduce them to x^3+1 and then compute the GCD, you get x^3+1, which is an incorrect result.

Comment: That's actually what I have done in this program, a just change the divide step  to first  multiply b(x) by p/GCD(p, q) ,and substract it to a(x), these are both the method of long division. Also I forgot to implement that my homework result needs to be polynomial function with irreducible integral coefficients, that's why I have to do the step in Lines 43 to 67, sorry to tell you late.

Comment: Well, it's not quite the GCD, then.

Comment: You seem to be fond of an idiom in which you double assign to array elements.  For example, `Op1[i] = 0; Op1[i] = Op2[i];`.  Except possibly if the simple assignment operator were overloaded, the first assignments in such cases have no useful effect.  They serve only to obfuscate your code.

Comment: You have at least three separate places where you implement the same reduction of a polynomial's coefficients.  Avoiding such duplication is one of the things functions are for.  Simplifying and raising the level of abstraction of the caller's code is another.

Answer (score 1):

### General advice relevant to your code

#### Choose *one* language

As observed in comments, your code uses both features that are unique to C++ and features that are unique to C.  As a result, although the program is written mostly in C style, I would not expect any C compiler to accept it.  Chances are better that a C++ compiler would accept your particular code and do the right thing with it, but that does rely on an extension that you will not find in some C++ compilers.  Moreover, it is possible to write code that conforms both to C and to C++, but has different meaning in the two languages, and although that's not an issue with your particular code, it is an excellent reason to accept the mindset that C and C++ are different languages.

### Define and use appropriate data structures

The right data structures and clarify simplify code, making it easier to write, easier to read, easier to debug, and less prone to bugs in the first place.  Your particular code would benefit from a data structure that joins the polynomial coefficients and its degree in one unit.  For example,

```
#define ARRAY_MAX 1000

struct polynomial {
    int degree;
    long long coefficients[ARRAY_MAX];
};
```

#### Use functions

Applied effectively, functions will both to reduce code duplication and to raise the level abstraction.  Smaller code is usually easier to read and to debug, and tends to have the property that each bug needs to be fixed only in one place.  More abstract code is easier to reason about (to a point).  Also, a good factoring into functions is helpful for testing those functions separately, which in turn simplifies debugging.  And for me, at least, writing a function also tends to help me focus on the details of that function's particular job, its requirements, and its result, without being much distracted by the details of the code that I intend will use it.

For example, you have three different places where you use substantially the same code to perform coefficient reductions on polynomials.  These should all be replaced by calls to a function that serves the purpose.  Moreover, even after such a conversion, you would have multiple places where you compute GCDs.  That GCD computation should go into a function itself, leaving the reduction function simple enough that you can evaluate its correctness pretty easily by inspection.  Maybe something like this:

```
/*
 * Converts polynomial coefficients to an irreducible canonical form by dividing
 * them by their greatest common denominator and inverting them if necessary to
 * ensure that the coefficient of the highest-order term is positive.
 *
 * No effect if all the coefficients are zero, and all other degree-0 polynomials
 * are reduced to the constant 1.
 */
void reduce_polynomial(struct polynomial *poly) {
    long long coef_gcd = poly->coefficients[0];

    for (int i = 1; i <= poly->degree && coef_gcd > 1; ++i) {
        coef_gcd = gcd(coef_gcd, poly->coefficients[i]);
    }

    if (coef_gcd != 0) {
        if (coef[degree] < 0) {
            coef_gcd = -coef_gcd;
        }
        for (i = 0; i <= poly->degree; i++) {
            poly->coefficients[i] /= coef_gcd;
        }
    } // else the coefficients and coef_gcd are all zero
}
```

That assumes that the gcd function (also to be supplied by you) does a suitable thing when an argument is zero: if either argument is zero, then the result is the other argument (including if both are zero).

#### Minimize copying

The code presented does rather a lot of copying of the coefficient arrays.  Sometimes copying is an appropriate thing to do, but needless copying is wasteful of both time and memory.  And a fair amount of the program's copying is needless.

In some cases, it is much to your advantage to copy pointers to objects instead of copying the objects themselves (though this is more fraught in idiomatic C++ than in C).  You could use that to good effect in implementing Euclid's algorithm for polynomials.  It could look more like this:

```
struct polynomial *poly1 /* = ... */;
struct polynomial *poly2 /* = ... */;

reduce_polynomial(poly1);

while (poly2->degree > 0) {
    reduce_polynomial(poly2);
    mod_polynomial(poly1, poly2); // result returned in *poly1
    struct polynomial *temp = poly1;
    poly1 = poly2;
    poly2 = temp;
}
```

Now *that's* actually recognizable as Euclid's!  And there's no storage needed for an extra copy of the coefficients, and there's very little work involved in performing the swap.

### Specific comments about issues in your code

**Your code is inconsistent about the data type used to represent polynomial coefficients.**  The main storage for them uses type `long long`, but you frequently copy them into `long`s for GCD computation.  Where you can get away with `long` for the GCDs, you don't need `long long` for the main coefficient storage, but for problems where `long` is not sufficient for the main coefficient storage, attempting to stuff coefficients into `long`s will yield incorrect results.  If your program were otherwise completely correct, this is an issue that would be more likely to manifest for higher-degree inputs than for lower.

This is likely responsible for at least some of the incorrect results you observe.

**Even `long long` might not be enough.** It doesn't take all that many factors to exceed the range of `long long` by multiplication.  Consider how fast the factorial grows, for example: 21! is already too large to represent with a 64-bit integer.  The program's reductions to relatively prime coefficient sets will have some effect against that, but that effect will tend to be less for higher degree polynomials, because the GCDs of large coefficient sets will tend to be small.

This will also lead to incorrect results in some cases, including, I anticipate, some where coefficients of the correct algebraic are small enough to fit.  All the intermediate results need to fit, too.

**This looks wrong**, or at best useless:

> ```
>                     if(((Op1[deg1]>0&&Op2[deg2]<0&&Op1[deg1]<-Op2[deg2])||(Op1[deg1]<0&&Op2[deg2]>0&&Op2[deg2]>-Op1[deg1]))){
>                         gcd1=-gcd1;
>                         gcd2=-gcd2;
>                     }
> ```

Perhaps what is actually wanted there is to conditionally flip *one* of the GCDs to ensure that `Op1[deg1] * gcd2 == Op2[deg2] * gcd1` when the coefficients' signs differ.  But if that relationship does not already hold then flipping *both* GCDs doesn't help.  This is an issue that has less opportunity to manifest with low-degree inputs, though it ought to be possible to construct low-degree inputs specifically to trigger it.

(If the idea is instead to ensure that the new Op1 at the end of that step has a positive highest-order coefficient, so as to address the problem from that angle, then I don't see any reason to believe that the code presented would be effective for that purpose.)

Comment: "Even long long might not be enough.The program's reductions to relatively prime coefficient sets will have some effect against that, but that effect will tend to be less for higher degree polynomials, because the GCDs of large coefficient sets will tend to be small."            This is definitely the problem I want to solve!! From the examples I have to test there are lots of high order polynomial and I can't get the right result because of this reason. If you know how to solve this problem please tell me, or there's no way to solve it that I surely have to change the method of long division?

Comment: @バスタ, if indeed `long long` is not enough then you probably cannot use a built-in type for your coefficients.  You would instead want arbitrary-precision integers, such as GNU GMP and similar 3rd-party packages provide.  But be before you go to the trouble, do make sure that that's what's actually causing your trouble.  Running your code in a debugger to check that out.